# How to split a long-lived Sidekiq job into many short-lived jobs in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

So I'm building a website that calls a third-party API that can take from 20 seconds to 30 minutes to return a result. But I can't know this duration in advance so need to poll it frequently to check if the work is done (returns "COMPLETE" and the result) or not (returns "IN_PROGRESS"). Also, this API might be called many times from many users at the same time.

So I created a Sidekiq worker that checks the API every 5 seconds until it receives "COMPLETE", and only then it ends. But I've read that Sidekiq should only be doing short-lived jobs, and I'm struggling to get my head around how should I do it. Also I've been trying to search for an answer but I suspect I don't know the words to find what I'm looking for.

I'm sure there is a way I can tell my workers to call the API once, and if the result is "IN_PROGRESS" end but make sure another worker will do another API call to check, and so on and so on until the result is "COMPLETE".

Also, I guess this is also handy to better distribute the load in case many users demand the use of said API, because fewer workers can do more of this short-lived jobs.

This is my worker, which I hope clarifies what I'm doing right now:

```
class ThingProgressWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    @thing = Thing.find(id)
    @thing_api_call = ThingAPICall.new // This uses the ruby library of the API
    completed = false
    while completed == false
      result = @thing_api_call.get_result( { thing_job_name: @thing.job_name })
      if !result.include? "COMPLETED"
        completed = false
        sleep 5
      else
        completed = true
        @thing.status = "completed"
        @thing.save
        break
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So if the API takes ten minutes to go from "IN_PROGRESS" to "COMPLETED" this worker will be busy for that long, which I recon is not advised at all.

I've been thinking about this for some hours now and can't think of how should I do to make each API call its own job without having a worker busy until the API is done.

The only solution I've thought so far is having a master worker that calls another worker for each API call, but then I'll still have a worker busy for as long as the API takes to send the result.

I'd appreciate any help or directions!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the worker with a delay. for example:

```
class ThingProgressWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    @thing = Thing.find(id)
    @thing_api_call = ThingAPICall.new // This uses the ruby library of the API
      result = @thing_api_call.get_result( { thing_job_name: @thing.job_name })
      if !result.include? "COMPLETED"
        ThingProgressWorker.perform_in(1.minute, id)
      else
        completed = true
        @thing.status = "completed”
        @thing.save
      end
  end
end
```

This will add the worker to the queue but will not run it immediately but in the time you specify.

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't explain it properly. It's not that I want to delay the execution of the job, but rather that I want that loooooooooooong job to be split into shorter ones. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What I mean is that instead of the while loop you call again the worker from within itself if the process is not completed in the api. Therefore, you will have a short lived worker calling itself to perform again in x seconds or minutes. If you say delay 1 minute it will run 20 times in 20 minutes (few seconds each)

Comment: I half works but doesn't work completely. It does call itself with a delay (which is what I wanted), but it then keeps calling the ThingProgressWorker (itself) indefinitely, even after the job is done and the if loop should fall to do the part in the else statement.
Even when result.include? "COMPLETED" should be true, it never actually does go to the statements under `else`

Comment: Then now the issue is about the if condition. Can you show the API response when the task is completed?